# How would one "extend" an enum in a cross-compatible way?

Tags: c#, .net

This is more of a hypothetical question at the moment, but I feel it might be useful in certain cases, so please, bear with me.

Let's say you are working with a library that processes images. The types used by the library would look like this:

```cs
public class Image
{
    public virtual ImageFormat Format { get; }
    // ...
}

public enum ImageFormat
{
    Unknown,
    Png,
    Gif,
    Jpeg
}
```

This is fairly simple, nothing too complicated, but what if at some point of working with the library, you actually add a support for another image format, but want to still make the code compatible with the library? Of course exposing this information for you only is not such a a big problem:

```cs
public class ExtendedImage : Image
{
    public override ImageFormat Format => ImageFormat.Unknown;
    public ExtendedImageFormat ExtendedFormat { get; }
}

public enum ExtendedImageFormat
{
  Bmp,
  Tiff,
  Webp
}
```

The problem is that if there are more libraries that all use this approach, you'd end up with a multitude of mutually incompatible formats which are externally just `ImageFormat.Unknown`.

Sure, the real problem is in the definition of `Image` and `ImageFormat`, and you could argue that switching from enum to a class or interface would solve this problem properly. However, let's say you don't have control over the library and you cannot modify it as other libraries rely on it (it might even be the BCL).

To make things even harder, let's say you *have* to actually store the extended format in the old `ImageFormat`, for some reason, casting between the enum types as needed.

```
public enum ExtendedImageFormat // : ImageFormat
{
  Bmp = 100001,
  Tiff = 100002,
  Webp = 100003
}
```

Summed up, what I am thinking about is a solution that has these properties:

- Given an `ImageFormat` value, it should be able to retrieve what one usually needs to retrieve from an enum value: its name and custom attributes. It *does not* have to be via `ToString` and reflection (it cannot be anyway).
- Given a string name, it should be able to parse it and get back the `ImageFormat` value.
- These capabilities should be usable from any other module/library, and a change from one module should be visible in another one.
- The modules that are "communicating" this way need not know (reference) themselves.
- The way new enum values are "registered" should be foolproof: registering a duplicate name/value should be detectable.
- The solution should not have any aspects that feel "arbitrary", i.e. custom names, types, information hidden in some resources etc. Preferrably it should be straightforward and something that one could arrive upon after some thought.
- I suppose there is nothing in .NET that solves this precise issue, so it could simply be a series of steps to follow (a couple of methods practically). Optimally, it should be restricted to .NET Standard 2.0.

I am thinking here in terms of classes like [`TypeDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor) which allows you to add members to existing types and objects. I am well aware that it's "fake" in some way, as it won't actually override existing methods nor affect reflection, but it's the kind of standardized solution that I am looking for, working for everyone as long as they use it everywhere. Therefore pointing to a library that handles all this registration on its own might be useful, but only if there is not a better solution using solely the base .NET libraries.

Comment: What is the _actual_ library you're using?

Comment: If this is all your code, you could conceive of some carefully thought out interfaces and potentially delegates and a plugin or composition system. Good luck

Comment: @Dai None; it's hypothetical as I said. But what made me think of the question in the first place was SharpCompress which has the `ArchiveType` enum. `IArchive` could be easily implemented by external code, but using the enum to specify the type of the archive is the issue.

Comment: @IS4 You shouldn't use `enum` for an open-ended or extensible set of values (and any libraries that do _have a broken design_). You should use a type-hierarchy instead.

Comment: @Dai Well I have already said that in the question. *Given* this kind of unchangeable library design, what do to, that is the question.

Comment: @IS4 You said this was a hypothetical - so if you **actually** have an "unchangeable library" then this **isn't** a hypothetical. Please clarify.

Comment: @Dai It is hypothetical in that I am not facing this issue in my own code at the moment. The unchangeable library is the premise however, as obviously I could very well solve it without this presupposition. Speaking of the hypothetical library, it could very well be something in the BCL itself, just look at descendants of [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum). Maybe [ExpressionType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressiontype) would be a good candidate if you wanted to make your own expression type.

Comment: In line with what @Dai said. Create the 'right' structure and create an ImageFormatConverter class that implements a method like U Convert<T,U>(T format) which contains some lookup tables. Then use some dependency injection to use this class in the places that call the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while, but I think this code solves the problem:

```cs
internal class DerivedEnumProvider<TDerived, TBase> : TypeDescriptionProvider
    where TDerived : struct, Enum
    where TBase : struct, Enum
{
    static readonly Type derivedType = typeof(TDerived);
    static readonly Type baseType = typeof(TBase);
    static readonly Type underlyingType;
    static readonly ulong typeHash;

    static DerivedEnumProvider()
    {
        underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(derivedType);
        if(!underlyingType.Equals(Enum.GetUnderlyingType(baseType)))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(TDerived)} ({derivedType}) and {nameof(TBase)} ({baseType}) must have the same underlying type.");
        }
        typeHash = unchecked((uint)derivedType.GetHashCode());
    }

    readonly TypeConverter baseConverter;

    readonly List<TBase> valuesList = new();
    readonly TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection valuesCollection;
    readonly Dictionary<TBase, object> derivedMap = new();
    readonly Dictionary<TDerived, object> baseMap = new();

    public DerivedEnumProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider parent, TypeConverter converter, ICollection standardValues) : base(parent)
    {
        baseConverter = converter;

        var valuesSet = new HashSet<TBase>();

        // Store all existing values
        foreach(var obj in standardValues)
        {
            if(!(obj is TBase value))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The standard values must be of type {nameof(TBase)} ({baseType}).", nameof(standardValues));
            }
            valuesSet.Add(value);
            valuesList.Add(value);
        }
        // Get all to-be-mapped values, as dynamic for arithmetics
        foreach(dynamic obj in Enum.GetValuesAsUnderlyingType(derivedType))
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var derivedValue = (TDerived)obj;

                // Get the mapped value
                var value = (TBase)(dynamic)((ulong)obj ^ typeHash);
                if(valuesSet.Add(value))
                {
                    valuesList.Add(value);
                    derivedMap[value] = derivedValue;
                    baseMap[derivedValue] = value;
                }else{
                    // Try the hash code of the reference
                    var refHashCode = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode((object)obj);

                    // Cast to the underlying type
                    dynamic initial = Convert.ChangeType((TBase)(dynamic)refHashCode, underlyingType);

                    // Loop over all values until we get back
                    dynamic attempt = initial;
                    do
                    {
                        var attemptValue = (TBase)attempt;
                        if(valuesSet.Add(attemptValue))
                        {
                            // This value was not used yet
                            valuesList.Add(attemptValue);
                            derivedMap[attemptValue] = derivedValue;
                            baseMap[derivedValue] = attemptValue;
                            attempt = null!;
                            break;
                        }
                    }while(++attempt != initial);
                            
                    if((object?)attempt != null)
                    {
                        throw new NotSupportedException($"The values of {nameof(TDerived)} ({derivedType}) do not fit into {nameof(TBase)} ({baseType}).");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // All values have been mapped
        valuesCollection = new(valuesList);
    }

    public override Type GetReflectionType(Type objectType, object? instance)
    {
        if(instance is TBase value && derivedMap.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            return derivedType;
        }
        return base.GetReflectionType(objectType, instance);
    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor? GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object? instance)
    {
        if(instance is TBase value && derivedMap.TryGetValue(value, out var derived))
        {
            // Delegate to the descriptor of derived
            return new Descriptor(this, TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(derivedType).GetTypeDescriptor(derived));
        }
        return new Descriptor(this, base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance));
    }

    class Descriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        readonly DerivedEnumProvider<TDerived, TBase> provider;

        public Descriptor(DerivedEnumProvider<TDerived, TBase> provider, ICustomTypeDescriptor? parent) : base(parent)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public override TypeConverter? GetConverter()
        {
            return new Converter(provider, TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(derivedType));
        }
    }

    bool BaseToDerived(TBase baseValue, [NotNullWhen(true)] out object? derivedValue)
    {
        return derivedMap.TryGetValue(baseValue, out derivedValue);
    }

    bool DerivedToBase(TDerived derivedValue, [NotNullWhen(true)] out object? baseValue)
    {
        return baseMap.TryGetValue(derivedValue, out baseValue);
    }

    class Converter : TypeConverter
    {
        static readonly Type stringType = typeof(string);

        readonly DerivedEnumProvider<TDerived, TBase> provider;

        TypeConverter baseConverter => provider.baseConverter;
        readonly TypeConverter derivedConverter;

        public Converter(DerivedEnumProvider<TDerived, TBase> provider, TypeConverter derivedConverter)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
            this.derivedConverter = derivedConverter;
        }

        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return derivedType.Equals(sourceType) || baseConverter.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, Type? destinationType)
        {
            return derivedType.Equals(destinationType) || baseConverter.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object? ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object value)
        {
            if(value is TDerived derivedValue)
            {
                if(provider.DerivedToBase(derivedValue, out var result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
                // Do not allow other derived conversions
                return null;
            }else if(value is string stringValue)
            {
                if(derivedConverter.ConvertFrom(context, culture, stringValue) is TDerived derivedValue2)
                {
                    if(provider.DerivedToBase(derivedValue2, out var result))
                    {
                        // Prefer derived conversion
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Prefer base conversion
            return
                baseConverter.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value) ??
                TryGetBase(derivedConverter.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value));
        }

        public override object? ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, CultureInfo? culture, object? value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if(value is TBase baseValue)
            {
                if(provider.BaseToDerived(baseValue, out var result))
                {
                    if(derivedType.Equals(destinationType))
                    {
                        return result;
                    }else if(stringType.Equals(destinationType))
                    {
                        // Prefer derived conversion
                        return derivedConverter.ConvertTo(context, culture, result, stringType);
                    }
                    // Prefer base conversion
                    return
                        baseConverter.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType) ??
                        derivedConverter.ConvertTo(context, culture, result, destinationType);
                }
            }
            return baseConverter.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }

        public override StandardValuesCollection? GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
        {
            return provider.valuesCollection;
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, object? value)
        {
            if(value is TBase baseValue)
            {
                if(provider.BaseToDerived(baseValue, out var derived))
                {
                    return derivedConverter.IsValid(derived);
                }
            }
            return baseConverter.IsValid(context, value);
        }

        public override object? CreateInstance(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, IDictionary propertyValues)
        {
            return
                baseConverter.CreateInstance(context, propertyValues) ??
                TryGetBase(derivedConverter.CreateInstance(context, propertyValues));
        }

        private object? TryGetBase(object? derived)
        {
            return derived is TDerived derivedValue && provider.DerivedToBase(derivedValue, out var baseValue) ? baseValue : null;
        }

        public override bool GetCreateInstanceSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
        {
            return baseConverter.GetCreateInstanceSupported(context) || derivedConverter.GetCreateInstanceSupported(context);
        }

        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection? GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext? context, object value, Attribute[]? attributes)
        {
            if(value is TBase baseValue && provider.derivedMap.TryGetValue(baseValue, out var derivedValue))
            {
                return derivedConverter.GetProperties(context, derivedValue, attributes);
            }
            return baseConverter.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
        }

        public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext? context)
        {
            return baseConverter.GetPropertiesSupported(context) || derivedConverter.GetPropertiesSupported(context);
        }
    }

    static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void MakeDerived()
    {
        lock(syncRoot)
        {
            // Check that the converter is usable
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(baseType);
            if(!(
                converter.GetStandardValuesSupported() &&
                converter.GetStandardValuesExclusive() &&
                converter.GetStandardValues() is { Count: > 0 } standardValues
                ))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(TBase)} ({baseType}) does not provide an exclusive list of values.");
            }
            var parent = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(baseType);
            // Construct and add the provider
            var derived = new DerivedEnumProvider<TDerived, TBase>(parent, converter, standardValues);
            TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(derived, baseType);
        }
    }
}
```

It could be used like this:

```cs
DerivedEnumProvider<CustomConsoleColor, ConsoleColor>.MakeDerived();

var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ConsoleColor));
foreach(ConsoleColor value in converter.GetStandardValues())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{value} = {converter.ConvertToInvariantString(value)} ({TypeDescriptor.GetReflectionType(value).Name})");
}

enum CustomConsoleColor
{
    Ochre,
    Olive,
    Lime,
    Scarlet
}
```

Which prints something like:

```
Black = Black (ConsoleColor)
DarkBlue = DarkBlue (ConsoleColor)
DarkGreen = DarkGreen (ConsoleColor)
DarkCyan = DarkCyan (ConsoleColor)
DarkRed = DarkRed (ConsoleColor)
DarkMagenta = DarkMagenta (ConsoleColor)
DarkYellow = DarkYellow (ConsoleColor)
Gray = Gray (ConsoleColor)
DarkGray = DarkGray (ConsoleColor)
Blue = Blue (ConsoleColor)
Green = Green (ConsoleColor)
Cyan = Cyan (ConsoleColor)
Red = Red (ConsoleColor)
Magenta = Magenta (ConsoleColor)
Yellow = Yellow (ConsoleColor)
White = White (ConsoleColor)
54267293 = Ochre (CustomConsoleColor)
54267292 = Olive (CustomConsoleColor)
54267295 = Lime (CustomConsoleColor)
54267294 = Scarlet (CustomConsoleColor)
```

Such a feat is possible thanks to the following "tricks", using various types in `System.ComponentModel`:

- `TypeDescriptor.AddProvider` makes it possible to "modify" existing types and add custom properties, conversions, etc. All this is limited only to other types in `System.ComponentModel`, so if you stick to low-level reflection, nothing will break, but more high-level applications (such as component designers in forms) will pick these modifications.
- `TypeDescriptor.GetReflectionType` returns the type designated for (low-level) reflection. If you wanted to find attributes for a particular enum field, this sounds like the method to use. Of course at this point you may also craft a custom `Type` instance (for example with `TypeDelegator`) that fakes all the newly added fields, which is a bit more complex but may integrate better with existing reflection-based code.
- `TypeConverter.GetStandardValues` is what most design-time components actually use to obtain a collection of usable values, and it works very well with enums or other similar types (`boolean`, cultures...). In theory, non-enum types could be extended in a similar manner.

It should be noted that this is more of a proof-of-concept, so there are some things that should be noted:

- The enums should have the same underlying type. This is not a fundamental restriction and could be removed.
- Flags (indicated by `GetStandardValuesExclusive`) are not supported. This would require more complex handling for situation when flags are combined and probably would not work with the current approach.
- The `TDerived` enum should not itself be derived from or otherwise modified. Theoretically it doesn't have to be an enum at all, any arbitrary collection of key/value pairs could be used, with mapping created as necessary.
- The code that maps one enum's values to the other might be sub-optimal. It's not such a big deal since it has to be called only once per pair of enums, but there could be better distribution or mapping strategies. The code first tries to XOR each individual value with the hash code of the type, so the values may form a sort of "contiguous" range, but if that does not work, other "random" values are tried.
- The implementation of `TypeConverter` might not be complete; other conversions could be considered and sometimes the order might not be intuitive.
- Duplicate names are considered, since it only affects string parsing. It should be fairly easy to implement additional handling.